# Путь к корню сайта

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

Как изменить путь к корню сайта?Обычно на локальном сервере, если ввести в строку браузера `localhost/`, то начнется загружаться файл `index.php`, который лежит в корне сайта, например, `localhost/www/index.php`. А мне надо, чтобы при вводе `localhost/` файл `index.php` искался в папке `public` (`localhost/www/public/index.php`). Так вот как и где изменить путь к корню сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf как то так

Comment: И что в нем надо изменить ?

Comment: DocumentRoot /путь/к/корню/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Сперва бы спросить у него, каким сервером он пользуетсяЯ бы сказал, что настройки в /etc/ligttpd/lighttpd.conf в строчке в server.document-root